# slick - use pause on hover on hover the tile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abgq3.png)
I working on a slick carousel as showing in the following image.
i want to pause my slick carousel by hover on the tiles.
for now its working for complete slick.
i want to pause the slick just hover on the tile.

```js
 $(this).slick({
slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    pauseOnHover: ? ,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplaySpeed:3000,arrows: true,dots: true,
                    infinite: false,
                    initialSlide: 0,
                    mobileFirst: true,
                    swipe: false,
                    draggable: false,
                    swipeToSlide: false,
                    touchMove: false,
                    responsive: [
                        {
                       breakpoint: 767,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 2,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1023,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1279,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                });
```

its working on complete slick but now I want to use only tiles for pause the slick slides.